# How to drop rows in an H2OFrame?

Tags: python, h2o

I've worked in the h2o R package for quite a while, now, but have recently had to move to the python package.

For the most part, an `H2OFrame` is designed to work like a pandas `DataFrame` object. However, there are several hurdles I haven't managed to get over... in Pandas, if I want to drop some rows:

```
df.drop([0,1,2], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do the same with an `H2OFrame`:

```
frame.drop([0,1,2], axis=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-0eff75c48e35> in <module>()
----> frame.drop([0,1,2], axis=0)

TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Their [github](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/h2o/frame.py#L1175) source documents that the drop method is only for columns, so obviously the obvious way isn't working:

```
def drop(self, i):
    """Drop a column from the current H2OFrame.
```

Is there a way to drop rows from an `H2OFrame`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the `H2OFrame.drop` method does not support this, but we have added a [ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3132) to add support for dropping multiple rows (and multiple columns).

In the meantime, you can subset rows by an index:

```
import h2o
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

hf = h2o.H2OFrame([[1,3],[4,5],[3,0],[5,5]])  # 4 rows x 2 columns
hf2 = hf[[1,3],:]  # Keep some of the rows by passing an index
```

Note that the index list, `[1,3]`, is ordered.  If you try to pass `[3,1]` instead, you will get an error.  H2O will not reorder the rows, and this is its way of telling you that.  If you have a list of out-of-order indexes, just wrap the `sorted` function around it first.

```
hf2 = hf[sorted([3,3]),:]
```

Lastly, if you prefer, it's also okay to reassign the new subsetted frame to the original frame name, as follows:

```
hf = hf[[1,3],:]
```

Comment: Hadn't even crossed my mind to slice it like a numpy array. Thanks!

Comment: Using `axis` argument also works: `df = df.drop([0,1,2], axis=0)`. But `inplace` does not

Answer (score 4):

Since this is now supported I wanted to highlight the comment that says how to drop by index:

`df = df.drop([0,1,2], axis=0)`

where if axis = 1 (default), then it drop columns; if axis=0 then drop rows.

`drop(index, axis=1)`

where index is a list of column indices, column names, or row indices to drop; or a string to drop a single column by name; or an int to drop a single column by index.